# Python exception syntax difference?

Tags: python, exception, syntax, error-handling

I am just being curious about the syntax of python exceptions as I can't seem to understand when you are suppossed to use the syntax below to catch an exception.

```
try:
    """
      Code that can raise an exception...
    """
 except Exception as e:
     pass
```

and

```
try:
    """
      Code that can raise an exception...
    """
 except Exception, e:
     pass
```

What is the difference?

Comment: I guess I wasn’t keen thanks @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** As Martijn points out, `comma variable` form is deprecated in Python 3.x. So, its always better to use `as` form.

As per http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

```
except Exception, e:
```

is equivalent to

```
except Exception as e:
```

Commas are still used when you are catching multiple exceptions at once, like this

```
except (NameError, ValueError) as e:
```

Remember, the parentheses around the exceptions are mandatory when catching multiple exceptions.

Comment: Except that the latter is preferred, the former deprecated and completely removed in Python 3.

Comment: Your last line shows **why** `as` was introduced to replace the comma. It was confusing as hell when multiple exceptions were being caught. Use `except (NameError, ValueError) as e:` there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got you :) Updated it

Comment: It was common to write the latter as `except NameError, ValueError:` and wonder why it didn't work, or use `except (NameError, e):` and wonder why you still got a `NameError` on `e`.

Comment: You are still implying that you can only catch multiple exceptions with the now-deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`except Exception, e` is deprecated in Python 3.

The proper form is:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

See: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110

Comment: The comma form is not just deprecated in Python 3; it is **removed** altogether.